# Realm Android Migration to change primary key data type not writing data

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I am using Realm android and wanted to change data type of existing primary key using Migration.

I used following code for Migration

```
schema.get("Test")
      .addField("id_new", String.class)
      .removeField("id")
      .addPrimaryKey("id_new")
      .renameField("id_new", "id");
```

Above code is migrating the schema without breaking, but if I try to write data in the new schema it is failing.

I don't want to persist any older data and thus not using transform method.

Comment: What do you mean it is failing when you try to write data to the new schema? An example + stacktrace of that would be good.

Comment: define `is failing`

Comment: When I try to fetch data after storing it gives me empty results and while writing data it does not provide any failure error message.

Comment: `removeField()` is deleting the data for that property/field for all objects of type "Test".

Comment: Check my answer. Is it does not help you?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to persist data, you can just call *deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()* method of builder:

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                          .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                          .build();
```

but I think, it's posable ONLY for development cycle of application.

Released applications MUST have real migrations scripts. For yours question, I suggest to use:

```
schema.get("Test")
  .addField("id_new", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
  .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
                    @Override
                    public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
                        // yuors transformation from id to id_new
                    }
                })
  .removeField("id")
  .renameField("id_new", "id");
```

See also:

[Official docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations)

[Migration sample class](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/model/Migration.java)